# Determining the distribution of fitted values and residuals

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, normality-assumption

For exam prep, we're supposed to answer this question (which we are supposed to be able to find the answer to in the course literature)

> For the model specified in a) and proper normality assumptions on ε, obtain the distribution of ŷ and e = y − ŷ

where the model referred to in a) is the standard form of the multiple regression model

\begin{equation}
\mathbf y = \mathbf X \pmb \beta + \pmb \epsilon
\end{equation}

with all proper normality assumptions fulfilled. I've been trying to find the answer in the chapter covering multiple regression in *Introduction to Linear Regression Analysis* (which is our course literature) and online, but I can't seem to find the answer.

Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi! Can't you ask the professor?

Comment: See [this search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=coefficient+estimate*+normal+regression+-error)